# Microsoft teams- User is unable to navigate to custom channel tab from the notification received under the 'Posts' tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

**Context**

Consider the use case where User A and User B are part of some Microsoft Team  'Team ABC' having default channel 'General'. Here, User A installs our application Safe Spaces (a channel tab application) to the channel 'General' of 'Team ABC'. While doing so, Microsoft pushes a notification into the 'Posts' tab of the channel (for reference please refer to the attached image) [image]

When User A clicks on such notification, he/she is being navigated to the installed channel tab.
However, when User B clicks the same notification from the 'Posts', he/she is getting the message that 'App has been deleted' in iOs devices, and in android devices, it shows a blank screen.
Although the same use case works fine in chrome browser with Microsoft team's web application.

Any thoughts or way around for the same?

Comment: we tried to repro this issue at our end but everything is working fine at our end in mobile devices. Could you please check if new instance of that app is added and you are clicking on older instance tab notification? It generally happens in that case

Comment: Does the above recommendation helped in any way or are you still facing the issue?

Comment: No - @Prasad-MSFT it's happening with us. Have you tried that use case simultaneously i.e. be on both the devices like chrome browser and mobile app and add tab to chrome in the same team and try that notification on device

Comment: Yes @Kapil, i tried in that way but not able to repro it. Its working fine in our case